# A Chain Rule for a Partial Derivative wrt $\text{Im}(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

### Question

Put simply, is the following equation correct? If not, why not?
With $g : \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable and $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic,
$$
    \frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial y}(z)
\hspace{1mm}=\hspace{1mm}
    \frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(f(z)) \hspace{0.8mm} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z).
$$
Note: I think it's not correct because, when I tried to use this to prove some other results, I got bogus outcomes.
However, I can't find any error in my work (below)... Anyway, I hate to be that guy who asks "what's wrong with the following proof," but essentially that is what I'm asking.

Thank you, for any insight into the matter.

### My work

Note that, throughout, $h$ will be referring to a real number.
Fix $z=x+iy$.
To start, we have
$$
    \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{
        f(z+ih) - f(z)
    }{h}
\hspace{1mm}=:\hspace{1mm}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z)
\hspace{1mm}=:\hspace{1mm}
    F
$$
and
$$
    \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{
        g(f(z)+ih) - g(f(z))
    }{h}
\hspace{1mm}=:\hspace{1mm}
    \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(f(z))
\hspace{1mm}=:\hspace{1mm}
    G.
$$
For every real $h$, write
$$
    v(h)
\hspace{1mm}:=\hspace{1mm}
    f(z+ih) - f(z) - hF.
$$
Similarly, define
$$
    w(h)
\hspace{1mm}:=\hspace{1mm}
    g(f(z)+ih) - g(f(z)) - hG.
$$
Then, $v(h)/h \to 0$ and $w(h)/h \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, also $w(0)=v(0)=0$.
Moreover, for every $h$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(z+ih)
\hspace{2mm}&=\hspace{2mm}
    f(z) + v(h) + h{
        F
    },
\\
    g(f(z)+ih)
\hspace{2mm}&=\hspace{2mm}
    g(f(z)) + w(h) + h{
        G
    }.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, we compute
$$
    g(f(z+ih))
\hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm}
    g\hspace{-0.6mm}\left(
        f(z) + v(h) + hF
    \right)
\hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm}
    g\hspace{-0.6mm}\left(\hspace{-0.6mm}
       f(z) + i \hspace{0.8mm} \frac{v(h) + hF}{i}
    \right)
\hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm}
    g(f(z)) + w\hspace{-0.6mm}\left(
        \frac{v(h) + hF}{i}
    \right) + \frac{v(h) + hF}{i} \: G
$$
where the last equality is from taking $\frac{v(h) + hF}{i}$ in place of $h$ in our expression for $g(f(z)+ih)$.
Then, subtracting $g(f(z))$ from both sides, dividing by $h$ gives
$$
    \frac{g(f(z+ih)) - g(f(z))}{h}
\hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm}
    \frac{1}{h} \hspace{0.8mm} w\hspace{-0.6mm}\left(
        \frac{v(h) + hF}{i}
    \right)
    +
    \left(
        \frac{v(h)}{h} + F
    \right) \frac{G}{i}.
$$
Since $v(h)/h \to 0$, we also have $v(h) \to 0$ and, indeed,
$
    \frac{v(h) + hF}{i} \to 0
$
as $h\to0$. Long story short, we've
$$
    \lim_{h\to0} \frac{1}{h} \hspace{0.8mm} w\hspace{-0.6mm}\left(
        \frac{v(h) + hF}{i}
    \right)
\hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm}
    \lim_{h\to0} \frac{v(h) + hF}{hi} \hspace{0.8mm} \frac{i}{v(h) + hF} \hspace{0.8mm} w\hspace{-0.6mm}\left(
        \frac{v(h) + hF}{i}
    \right)
\hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm}
    \frac{F}{i} \hspace{0.8mm} 0
\hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm}
    0,
$$
which leaves
$$
    \lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(f(z+ih)) - g(f(z))}{h}
\hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm}
    \lim_{h\to0}
    \left(
        \frac{v(h)}{h} + F
    \right) \frac{G}{i}
\hspace{2mm}=\hspace{2mm}
    \frac{FG}{i}.
$$

Comment: why is $(v(h)+hF)/i$ real, so can play the role of $h$? the correct formula is just the usual change of varaible one If $f=u+iv$ then $\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial y}(z)=g_1(f(z))u_y(z)+g_2(f(z))v_y(z)$ where $g_1, g_2$ are the original partial derivatives of $g$ and $u_y, v_y$ are the partial derivatives of $u,v$ wr $y$

Comment: Aha, that is indeed a problem with my work! You're right that $(v(h)+hF)/i$ isn't real.